# Jquery keypress not working with socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io, hogan.js

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The following code is simply the most recent iteration of random shit I've tried:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/home.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            alert('You pressed enter!');
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using firefox. I'll post the app.js if necessary, but I'm pretty sure it's irrelevant for using jQuery to simply detect a button press and show an alert. I'm not even using any socket events yet. When I run the server that all works fine, but when I press enter nothing happens. Here's my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var path = require('path');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {title:'test'});
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

Comment: <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> should be <script src="//socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> - Only thing I see wrong in your page.

Answer (score 1):

Missing `</head>` and `<body>` on the html file.

I updated and it worked for me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/home.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            alert('You pressed enter!');
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still not working on my Windows 7 machine with Firefox 41. If interested, see my other comment for more details.

Comment: You may want to try on a different browser. Also you can check if you blocking pop ups or have any FF extension that blocks pop ups. I tested on FF, Chrome and Safari and all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Update your jquery version use:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Also remove the unnecesary $(document).ready({}); function.

Use the following code:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
   if (e.which == 13) {
       alert('You pressed enter!');
   }
});
```

or use this one:

```
$(document).bind("keydown",function (e) {
   if (e.which == 13) {
       alert('You pressed enter!');
   }
});
```

Check the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hacker1211/bk56hg5k/

Comment: Tried all four of your suggestions. Nothing... Thanks though. I'll put my app.js in the edit.

Comment: please check the most recent edits and the fiddle link

Comment: jquery link should be: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: It works fine in fiddle, but it's still not working on my machine, with your edits or Alex's complete file. I even tried deleting all the socket.io stuff and simply running the html document in a browser. Nothing. I guess I'll just try drinking until the problem solves itself... Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I tried to run the same code in a notepad, saved it in a .html file and executed it. voila it executes !!!